# What are the 3D Analyse settings for Sands of Time?

Tags: technical-issues, prince-of-persia-the-sands-of-time

I want to play PoP Sands of Time but when it starts it shows a box saying "video card not supported". I have used 3D Analyse to play many games which I could not play before but I am still not able to play Sands of Time with it. Does anyone know the 3D Analyze settings needed to play it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with 3D-Analyse, but the settings which ought to work are: [image]

Props for the Youtube-user: