# 3D analyze and Prince of Persia Sands of Time

Tags: 3d-analyze, prince-of-persia-the-sands-of-time

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the 3D Analyse settings for Sands of Time?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/24029/what-are-the-3d-analyse-settings-for-sands-of-time)

When i use 3D analyze for Prince of Persia Sands of time, I get an error message:

> Couldnt copy D:\3d analyze\d3dhook.dll to C:\prince of persia sands of time\d3d hook.dll.

What can I do to fix this?

Here are my system specs:

- dual core 2.4 ghz
- 1gb ram
- g31/33 express chipset family

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/24029/what-are-the-3d-analyse-settings-for-sands-of-time

Comment: Just eliminating the obvious: Is the install path correct? Is there already a file in the target directory with the same name and if so, is is write enabled?

Comment: I don't suppose you have it on Steam?